# How to go to second page in kivymd python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have the first page with login and perform checking on the .py file with database (sqlite3). Now the problem is how do I go to another page after perform the checking. Here I use the sm.windowManager but it does not work and give me a blank page. Is there anything can help me to go to other page on the .py file instead on the .kv file on_press

Here is the code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sqlite3

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ReserveWindow(Screen):
    pass

class windowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = windowManager()
sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(ReserveWindow(name='Reserve'))


class Myapp(MDApp):
    connection = None
    connection = sqlite3.connect("book.db")
    cur = None
    def build(self):
        return sm

    def check(self,ID,password):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("book.db")
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("select mmu_id,password from User where mmu_id =(?) and password = (?)", (ID, password))
        exists = c.fetchall()
        if exists:
            sm.current = 'Reserve'
        else:
            print("Error: Wrong ID or password.")


Myapp().run()
```

Myapp.kv

```
windowManager:
MainWindow:
ReserveWindow:
<MainWindow>:
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color : [1,1,1,1]
        MDCard :
            size_hint : None,None
            size : 320,400
            pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            elevation : 15
            padding: 20
            spacing : 30
            orientation : 'vertical'
            MDLabel :
                text : 'Login'
                font_style : 'Button'
                font_size : 45
                halign : 'center'
                size_hint_y : None
                height : self.texture_size[1]
            MDTextFieldRound:
                hint_text : 'MMU Id'
                id : ID
                icon_right : 'account'
                size_hint_x : None
                width : 240
                font_size: 20
                pos_hint : {"center_x":.5}
            MDTextFieldRound:
                hint_text : 'password'
                id: password
                icon_right : 'eye-off'
                size_hint_x : None
                width : 240
                font_size: 20
                pos_hint : {"center_x":.5}
            MDRoundFlatButton :
                text : 'SIGN-IN'
                pos_hint : {"center_x":.5}
                font_size : 15
                md_bg_color : [118/255,251/255,130/255,1]
                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                text_color: [0,0,0,1]
                on_press: app.check(ID.text,password.text)
            Widget:
                size_hint_y : None
                height : 15

<ReserveWindow>:
    MDScreen:
        MDLabel :
            text : 'Page 2'
```

Comment: What is the name of your `kv` file?

Comment: Myapp.kv, I already edit the question ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```
sm = windowManager()
sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(ReserveWindow(name='Reserve'))
```

build your widget tree. However the lines in your `kv` file:

```
windowManager:
    MainWindow:
    ReserveWindow:
```

also build a widget tree (but without the required `name` properties for each `Screen`).

I recommend changing you `kv` to include the `names`:

```
windowManager:
    MainWindow:
        name: "Main"
    ReserveWindow:
        name: "Reserve"
```

And using that to build your widget tree in your `App`:

```
# sm = windowManager()
# sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='Main'))
# sm.add_widget(ReserveWindow(name='Reserve'))


class Myapp(MDApp):
    connection = None
    connection = sqlite3.connect("book.db")
    cur = None
    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_file('Myapp.kv')
        return sm

    def check(self,ID,password):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("book.db")
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute("select mmu_id,password from User where mmu_id =(?) and password = (?)", (ID, password))
        exists = c.fetchall()
        if exists:
            self.root.current = 'Reserve'
        else:
            print("Error: Wrong ID or password.")
```

Note that naming your `kv` file as `my.kv` would allow it to be loaded automatically and you could eliminate the `build()` method entrely (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)). But that would required a change in your `check()` method.

Comment: Thanks it works well. But do you have any idea how can I go to the second page which is "ReserveWindow" on my .py file after it performs the cheking.

Comment: Forgot to include that change, See the `check()` method in my updated answer